# Updated JQuery - get Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'jQuery' is undefined

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, telerik, internet-explorer-9

All was good until I updated Jquery and now I get get Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'jQuery' is undefined  in jquery.validate.min.js- I am at a loss as to what to do.

MVC3 - using Telerik extensions controls - used nuget

_Layout.cshtml (valid paths)

I have tried both script and link tags:

```
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js")" rel="stylesheet" />
```

And I tried

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Also added to jQuery(false) to scriptregistrar tag

Packages.config

```
<package id="jQuery" version="1.7.1" />
<package id="jQuery.UI.Combined" version="1.8.17" />
<package id="jQuery.Validation" version="1.9" />
```

Visual Studio 2010 - running in IE9.
Any advice greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Load `jquery-1.7.1.min.js` **before** the `jquery.validate` plugins. And use `<script>`, not `<link>`.

`<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.min.js")"></script>`
   `<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")"></script>`
   `<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobstrusive.min.js")"></script>`

Comment: Worked like a charm.  Thank you for your quick response.

Comment: Nice to hear it worked for your purposes. I'd recommend accepting this answer as correct for future reference as well.