# Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'jQuery' is undefined

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I am an ASP MVC 3 noobie working my way through the music store tutorial http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-5

I have successfully added a StoreManager controller with Add/Edit/Delete operations. The controller works--I am able to perform these operations. But midway thru, visual studio shows pop ups that say "Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'jQuery' is undefined." I just ignore these errors and everything runs fine.

The SO post [Updated JQuery - get Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'jQuery' is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8981351/updated-jquery-get-microsoft-jscript-runtime-error-jquery-is-undefined) seems to imply that there might be a problem with my packages.config file. Is there something I need to fix in this file to make this error go away? How can I be sure that jQuery is installed and properly hooked up to MVC3/Visual Studio? I assume that jQuery was included when installed SP1 with the MVC 3 components.

Here is my packages.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="jQuery" version="1.5.1" />
  <package id="jQuery.vsdoc" version="1.5.1" />
  <package id="jQuery.Validation" version="1.8.0" />
  <package id="jQuery.UI.Combined" version="1.8.11" />
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="4.1.10331.0" />
  <package id="Modernizr" version="1.7" />
</packages>
```

Comment: That's nice. Verify the HTML/script references/resource download status.

Comment: @pst thanks. Where do I find the references? How do I check them?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This means that your script reference to jQuery*.js is broken, when another script tires to call jQuery this error is thrown.

Look at your markup usually in _Layout.cshtml and find the `<script>` references. There should be one similar to `<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>`

If you have updated jQuery using the package manager, the version number in the reference needs to be updated. `"~/Scripts/jquery-<version>.min.js"`

1. Make sure the path is valid.
2. Make sure its the first script
   referenced.
3. Test using Chrome/IE/FireFox debug tools

Answer (score 0):

If you have master page, can you check whether any other jQuery reference is added to the content page or not? Same JQuery reference should not be duplicated.