# Microsoft jscript runtime error: Object doesnt support this property or method

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I get this above error when I run the program in IE browser. 
I am using:
jquery-2.2.4.min.js
jQuery UI - v1.12.1
Bootstrap v3.3.6 and IE 8.

The second error is

2. Unhandled exception at line 14, column 3 in 
   http://localhost:51898/Scripts/jquery-ui.js

   0x800a1391 - Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'jQuery' is undefined
3. Unhandled exception at line 6, column 31 in http://localhost:51898/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js

   0x800a139e - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery

the order of scripts is

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
```

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11905205/6741868) out.

Comment: check jquery-2.2.4.min.js file is available in folder called Scripts....

Comment: @ShiwankaChathuranga Its available